# I am not getting onion url from IPV4 Address using python socket

Tags: python, onion-architecture

I am trying to get onion URL from IPV4 Address using python.

```
{
    try:
        return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)[0]
    except socket.gaierror:
       print(addr+":nodename nor servname provided, or not known")
       return None
    except socket.herror:
        print(addr+':Unknown host')
        return None
    except socket.timeout:
        print(addr+':Timeout')
        return None
}
```

But from `socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)[0]`, I can't get onion URL and I can get only well-know hostname.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, You need to run with this code

import subprocess 
import ipaddress 
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('5.0.0.0/24'): 
subprocess.call(["tor-resolve", "-x", ip])